# Bad score for Area Under ROC, but Area Under Precision-Recall is high?

Tags: apache-spark, classification, precision-recall, auc

I'm doing some classification in Apache Spark, and I am unsure how to interpret my results. I get a very bad auROC (0.53), but a very high auPR (0.79).

These results seem a bit contradictory to me, how should I interpret this?

Comment: I believe that this belongs on stackexchange

Comment: [I posted my question on StackExchange. Thanks for the heads up.](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/210823/bad-score-for-area-under-roc-but-area-under-precision-recall-is-high)